# What does the symbol $W_t$ mean in the SHA-256 specification?

Tags: hash, sha-256

I'm really confused about the computation about SHA 256.

$$W_t = \begin{cases}
M_t^{(i)} & 0 \leq t \leq 15 \\
&\\
\sigma_1^{256}(W_{t-2}) + W_{t-7} + \sigma_0^{256}(W_{t-15}) + W_{t-16} & 16 \leq t \leq 63 
\end{cases}$$

The $W_t$ variable: What's the value of $W_t$? How do I get that value?

I'm still confused because of the explanation using the English language. I'm a beginner guys, any help from you will be a plus point for me about hashing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is in SHA-256 message schedule ([NIST-FIPS 180-4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.180-4.pdf));

The message $M$ with length $l$ is first padded as the usual way;

- append 1 to the end of the message,
- then, add $k$ zero bits such that $$l+1+k \equiv 448 \mod 512$$
- finally, add the length of the message in 64-bit. Now, the total padded length is divisible by 512.

After padding, the padded message parsed into $M^{1},\ldots,M^{N}$ where each has size 512-bit.

The sub index $t$ represents 32-bits in 512 bits. Thus, The $M_t^{(i)}$ is the $t$-th 32-bit in the $M^{(i)}$ for $0 \leq t \leq 15$

The $W_t$ is defined as your equation;

$$W_t = \begin{cases}
M_t^{(i)} & 0 \leq t \leq 15 \\
&\\
\sigma_1^{256}(W_{t-2}) + W_{t-7} + \sigma_0^{256}(W_{t-15}) + W_{t-16} & 16 \leq t \leq 63 
\end{cases}$$

Where
$$\sigma_1^{256}(x) = \operatorname{ROTR}^{17}(x) \oplus  \operatorname{ROTR}^{19}(x) \oplus  \operatorname{SHR^{10}(x)}$$
$$\sigma_0^{256}(x) = \operatorname{ROTR}^{7}(x) \oplus  \operatorname{ROTR}^{18}(x) \oplus  \operatorname{SHR^{3}(x)}$$

$\sigma_1^{256}(x)$ and $\sigma_0^{256}(x)$ operate on 32 bits and produce 32 bits.

**Note:** the 256 above the $\sigma$ represents the 256 in SHA-256. Similarly, there is $\sigma_0^{512}(x)$ and $\sigma_1^{512}(x)$ for SHA-512.

Comment: so you mean Wt = M16.....Mn ?

Comment: No. $W_1 = M_1^{(i)}, W_2 = M_2^{(i)}, \ldots, W_{15} = M_{15}^{(i)}$

Comment: @OntaSs there is no $M_{16}$, the 16 words of the input block are numbered 0 to 15 only

Comment: @kelalaka Wt = M1 u mean (Wt-2) = (M1-2) ? sorry bro i learn self-taught about this. i got little confused if read mathematic formulas

Comment: @RichieFrame yeah i got it. How about W16....W63 ? what is the value ?

Comment: @OntaSs they are generated using the formula, so $W_{16}$ = $\sigma_1(W_{14}) + W_{9} + \sigma_0(W_{1}) + W_{0}$

Comment: @RichieFrame ok. What's the next ?

Comment: @RichieFrame maybe we can chat ? whatsapp or something else ?